# Explorer "Not Responding" After Creating New Folder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze, user-folders

When I create a new folder in Windows 10, sometimes Explorer will hang for 10-30 seconds with a message "Not Responding". The upper right corner of all Explorer windows will turn red during this time.

This is extremely annoying. This is a new Dell desktop computer and the problem has been happening since I bought it. Google searches indicate this is a common problem. But no solution has worked for me. The only "solution" I have found is to go into the Task Manager and Restart Windows Explorer. Which kills all my open windows.

I should add that my OS is on an SSD. I actually cloned the SSD onto a new SSD. So it is not a hardware problem with the OS drive. I have also run extensive memory tests. No hardware problem there, either.

Comment: Is this happening when you boot in Safe mode?

Comment: Look and see if you have "Stopped Working" errors in Reliability History. If Explorer is hanging up, the only cure I know is a Windows 10 Repair Install

Comment: Very possible that it is a shell extension misbehaving and not the explorer itself.  Use a tool like shell extension viewer to disable suspect 3rd party extensions.

Comment: If you're really struggling with this, I would download Procdump from Sysinternals/Microsoft when you have the issue run: `procdump -ma explorer.exe` to create a process dump when it's hanging.  Using WinDbg it is then possible to look at the threads of Explorer to see what they are waiting on.  There is a good chance, there will be a stack in which a third-party module is trying to do something.

Comment: John: Thank you for that tip. I never heard of this Reliability monitor before. Indeed, it found a hardware error as well as the Explorer crash. But I don't understand how to interpret these reports. I will paste them below. Can you tell me what to do with this information?

Comment: Source
Windows

Summary
Hardware error

Date
‎5/‎1/‎2020 6:38 PM

Status
Report sent

Description
A problem with your hardware caused Windows to stop working correctly.

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: LiveKernelEvent
Code: 117
Parameter 1: ffffe107882f4010
Parameter 2: fffff80681485850
Parameter 3: 0
Parameter 4: 50c
OS version: 10_0_18363
Service Pack: 0_0
Product: 768_1
OS Version: 10.0.18363.2.0.0.768.101
Locale ID: 1033

Comment: Helping Hand: Thank you for your tips. This was all new to me, too. I downloaded both those programs. I tested it under normal circumstances. The WinDbg Preview readout is pretty cryptic. What should I look for?

Comment: @RobertBernstein This is a huge topic and more than I can write in a comment but, first steps might be:`!uniqstack` this command will dump the unique stacks of all the threads in Explorer at the time of the dump.  I would go down each one, getting an overall picture of what the process is doing. Deeper threads tend to be more interesting and currently "up to something".  You can see the modules involved and it might hint as to what is going on. Explorer has a lot of threads!  `!runaway` might help focus in on threads that are busiest since process launch. `lm` and `!peb` commands are good.